# cscope not working with shortcuts in .vimrc file

Tags: linux, vim, tcsh, cscope

I am trying to add shortcuts to cscope usage by adding the following statements in .vimrc file.

```
" cscope mappings
if has("cscope")
nmap <C-\>s :scs find s <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
endif
```

I sourced the file using `:so ~/.vimrc` in the vim application.

However, when i click `Ctrl+\` and `s` my terminal hangs. Please help. My shell is `/usr/local/bin/tcsh`

Thanks

Chidambaram

Comment: Does it hang "forever" or just for a limited time? Does it work with `<C-\>` only?

Comment: Hi Romainl, It hangs forever.

Comment: It might be that Ctrl-S is somehow triggered (though it seems you're only pressing s unmodified), which locks the terminal.  Try Ctrl-Q and if it unlocks the terminal, at least you know that's the culprit.

Comment: @CHID Does it works without mapping?

Comment: Have you tried using the [cscope_maps.vim](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/cscope_maps.vim) plugin?

Answer (score 0):

The reason it hangs might be because you are not pressing the mapping correctly.
Press ctrl+\ then s .But you might be pressing ctrl+s that is causing the hang.
To make sure if it's ctrl+s that is the culprit try ctrl+q see if terminal restores then you can proceed.